# Display datas on modal dialog in angular4 application

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a angular 4 application and I want to display datas in dialog. So, I use `@Output` to pass data from child to parent component.

So, in the parent component I have :

```
export class DashboardComponent {
    myTask;


    public returnTask(task: any):void {
        console.log("returnTask");
        this.myTask = task;
        console.log(this.myTask);
    }
    openDialogEditTask() {
        console.log(this.myTask);
        let dialogRef = this.dialogEditTask.open(DialogEditTask, {
            //task
            data:  {
                start: this.myTask.start,
                end: this.myTask.end,
                status: this.myTask.status,
                user: this.myTask.user,
                content: this.myTask.content,
                id: this.myTask.id,
                rate: this.myTask.rate
            }
        });
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
            this.selectedOption = result;
        });
}
}
```

In the parent html, I have :

```
<visTimeline (myTask)="returnTask($event)"></visTimeline>
```

In the child component, I have :

```
export class VisTimelineComponent {
    @Output() myTask: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
}
```

And I emit the task with `self.myTask.emit(task);`

So, I get the datas in the parent component (I can see them in the console) but I can't use them in `openDialogEditTask` because it's undefined.

So, do you know how can I get the datas before calling the function to have the datas in the dialog ?

EDIT :
This is my code to emit datas in child component :

```
ngOnInit() {
    Timeline.prototype.onTaskDoubleClick = function(task) {
        console.log("Double click on task " + task.id);
        console.log(task);
        $('#editTask').click();
        self.myTask.emit(task);
    };
}
```

`Timeline.prototype.onTaskDoubleClick` is a function from a library.

Comment: When does the openDialogEditTask gets called?

Comment: how do you use the data in openDialogEditTask , make use of safe operator that might help like  data?.whatyouwant

Comment: openDialogEditTask is called on the click on a button : <button id="editTask" md-button (click)="openDialogEditTask()" style="display:none;">Edit Task</button>

Comment: What is a safe operator ?

Comment: You should show the button only when the task is ready like <button id="editTask" md-button (click)="openDialogEditTask()"  *ngIf="myTask " style="display:none;">Edit Task</button>

Comment: Is there a way to have the datas directly and not hiding the button ?

Comment: when are you emitting the event from child? can you share the code for that?

Comment: I added the code for the emitting in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not able to pass data into you modal component. try with componentInstance method.

```
    openDialogEditTask() {
        console.log(this.myTask);
        let dialogRef = this.dialogEditTask.open(DialogEditTask, {
            height: '90%',
            width: '80%'
        });
        dialogRef.componentInstance.myTaskValue = this.myTask; //<- passing data into DialogEditTask component
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
            this.selectedOption = result;
        });
}
```

in your DialogEditTask declare a variable `myTaskValue: any;`

you will get all your value you pass into DialogEditTask component in this myTaskValue variable

Comment: I am able to pass data into the modal component but I think I get the datas too late because openDialogEditTask is called before returnTask, so I don't have the informations when I open the dialog but I have them just after.

Comment: how do you open openDialogEditTask() function.Plz add more code. if you are calling it automatically after put this.openDialogEditTask() inside returnTask(). otherwise it can be issue of change detection. use ngZone in your code where you think change it not getting detected. add plnkr of your code if possible. @Adrien

Comment: I call openDialogEditTask() with a click on a button.

Comment: @Adrien try to put your emit of onTaskDoubleClick in ngZone of angular. it may be issue of change detection. check my this answer for how to use ngZone. i hope it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41096985/legacy-meteor-methods-angular2-ui-router-issue/41323922#41323922